# Is there anything wrong with this SSR circuit?

Tags: mosfet, relay, opto-isolator, zener, solid-state-relay

[image: Relay Circuit]

I am a mechanical engineering student currently interning at a small company. We make solenoid valves and some tests require that we cycle the valves many times. This is a circuit that I came up with for an optically isolated MOSFET relay. Ideally, the IN and OUT voltages should be the same. The opto-isolator is triggered by an Arduino Micro. The purpose of the zener diode is to guard the MOSFET gate against overvoltage as its Vgs is +-30 V and it is possible that some solenoids will require voltages greater than 30 V. I have already tested a breadboard prototype up to 28 V and it appears to work as I expect it to. Is there anything incorrect, unnecessary, or bad practice about this circuit? Or is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: How low can the solenoid test voltage go?  What's the maximum solenoid current?

Comment: Solenoid = backemf -> a "flywheel diode" is needed ...

Comment: Do you just want a yes as an answer, or also a list of problems? The Q&A format does not suit very well to design reviews, as each answer might point out a different issue.

Comment: The highest voltages I've personally seen are around 30 V, but I think we have some units that go as high as 60 V. As for current, most are around 1 to 2 A. I don't expect any to be higher than that.

Comment: AC or DC . . . . . ?

Comment: Looks goodish. add diode across solenoid as noted by others. || Gate zener is a really good idea even when Vsupply is < VGSmax as it will clamp miller coupled spikes from the drain - which can kill the FET. | As noted, switching speed is not super fast. Probably in 10+ uS range. | Note Vgate max is Vsupply/2 as shown. P7N60e datasheet - https://www.vishay.com/docs/91508/sihp7n60e.pdf - note it needs LOTS of gate drive. For large load currents your Vsupply/2 may be risky at low Vsupply values - see figs 1 & 2 in datasheet

Comment: VOTES TO CLOSE:  3 votes to close. If this is closed without detailed comment then I WILL edit and reopen. If voting to close please provide guidance as to what is required.

Comment: The switching of the MOSFET will be slow, due to the 10 K resistors in your drive circuit. Slow switching can result in heating of your MOSFET. It may or may not be an issue. If it is, you may want to add two transistors to your drive circuit in class B push-pull configuration. That is, one, NPN, one PNP, with emitters connected and bases connected. (Sorry, can't add schematics to comments).

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy ... Yes, you can ... Just add the schematic in an "answer" without posting ... copy and add the link in your comment :-)

Comment: Just add a "little" capacitor after the high driving 10k ... for a "high" initial pulse drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reverse-biased diode across the solenoid terminals to absorb the EMF generated when the solenoid current is suddenly shut off. This is also called a "free-wheeling" diode or a "flyback" diode. It is needed to protect the MOSFET.

Answer (score 1):

The optoisolator input is missing a resistor.

The FET gate is driven high and low via 10k resistors. This makes the FET turn on and off slowly. Be sure not to exceed the safe operating area limits where it dissipates a lot of power when is only halfway turned on.

And yes, the drain needs a diode to protect from the inductive kickback of the solenoid.

Comment: I do have a resistor in series with it, its just not shown on the diagram. I learned that the hard way unfortunately.

Comment: @RyanHardin Well the diagram is what we see and you get answers based on that. If it is not up to date then you will get answers that are not up to date.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a simpler way to do it?

[image: schematic]

The diode clamps higher voltages but also dampensor slows the recovery time of the solenoid. If that matters, use a TVS, to allow a higher voltage clamp and thus faster velocity return of the solenoid where back EMF V is limited by diode.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Some of the solenoids operate on the order of 1 or 2 ms opening and closing so the circuit would need to be at least that fast. Would you see that being an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks goodish.
Add diode across solenoid as noted by others.

Gate zener is a really good idea even when Vsupply is < VGSmax as it will clamp Miller effect coupled spikes from the drain - which can kill the FET.

As noted by others, switching speed is not super fast.
Probably in 10+ uS range due to RC time constant at gate.

Note:  Vgate max is Vsupply/2 as shown.
P7N60e [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91508/sihp7n60e.pdf) - note it needs LOTS of gate drive. For large load currents your Vsupply/2 may be risky at low Vsupply values - see figs 1 & 2 in datasheet. I'd say you want at least 14V on supply to give 7V on gate to allow full saturation at 4A load - so safe at 2A load with component variation.